# BeanDefinitionOverrideException although Spring-Property overriding is enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Although the spring-property `allow-bean-definition-overriding: true` is enabled in the main application.yml, I am getting an Exception. Any clue why?

Application Start

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'httpSessionManager', defined in class path resource [...], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in URL [...HttpSessionManager.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Test Start

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: Shouldn't really set allow-bean-definition-overriding: true, think it through why would you want this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error message, it says:

> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true.

Make sure your allow-bean-definition-overriding property is under the spring.main element.